# Can I post data to php page using YQL?

Tags: php, html, yahoo, yql

Can I post data to php page using YQL ?

Comment: Please, downvoters, *explain* your downvote.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

With an `<execute>` block ([docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html)), you can write JavaScript to make external HTTP requests: POSTs included. Have a read of one of Christian Heilmann's blog posts on the subject: [Using YQL to read HTML from a document that requires POST data](http://www.wait-till-i.com/2009/11/16/using-yql-to-read-html-from-a-document-that-requires-post-data/).

A brief example of the JavaScript to make such a request might look like:

```
// Prepare POST request
var url  = "http://www.postbin.org/1k2hsu7";
var body = "question=5579467&name=faressoft";
var req  = y.rest(url).accept('text/html').post(body);

// Make the request, and get response
var res  = req.response;

// Assign to YQL response object
response.object = res.body;
```